# How should I fix/resolve exception The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

I tried to load a project I have and got this exception:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

And each time I'm trying to reload the project while loading it I'm getting this window:

[image: Error]

I'm not sure what to download and where from.

And I can't change any of the project properties I'm getting error in all the properties windows.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version did you install? Which .NET SDK versions are installed on the machine? VS 2015 came with 4.6.1 since Service Pack 1. Visual Studio 2017 includes 4.7. Are you usinge a very old Visual Studio version perhaps?

Comment: If you select the second option Visual Studio will download the correct SDK itself. If you use an old VS version like 2010 you should *really really* consider upgrading to a recent one - 2017 or 2019, which comes out today.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [msbuild 14 doesn't work without full .net framework installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567540/msbuild-14-doesnt-work-without-full-net-framework-installation)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Either select "Download the targeting pack for..." from the dialog, or open the Visual Studio Installer, click "Modify" and select the 4.6.1 targeting pack from "Individual components":

[image]

Comment: And how do I get to the Installer ? Tried to find it but could not.

Comment: In Windows search for *Visual Studio Installer*

Answer (score 12):

Windows -> Search -> Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual Components and check the right version

Comment: Or, OP could just select 'Download the targeting pack for ".NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1' and download the correct target version directly from the dialog

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in his initial message he wrote : "Error The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found." So obviously he has to select this version :) even more obvious, he can just click download from that pop-up, but my solution is more general and a good to know one.

Comment: I tried to download from the dialog and got to this page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral But I have no clue what should I download there.

Comment: @user1196715 the thing you're looking for. The 4.6.1 SDK. If you simply search for `4.6.1` in that page you'll find it. What Visual Studio version are you using though? Recent versions should include this

Comment: @user1196715 just follow the steps in my initial answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My visual studio version is: Community 2017 version 15.9.6 and so fat it happened to me only on this project. Other projects mostly new never asked me this dialog.

Comment: @user1196715 yes there is. Yes, the version in in Visual Studio Installer. Lennart even posted a screenshot.

Comment: @user1196715 the search from your Windows bar.

Comment: Withdrawing all my comments. This is becoming a `How does Windows work` question

Comment: God. In the end the solution was to download the .NET Framework 4.6.1 Developer Pack on the page I provided before in my comments there is no SDK version 4.6.1 but there is a Framework version 4.6.1 and then you have to download the Developer Pack and not the Runtime.  Just guessed after some tries. Why they can't make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can directly download the targeting pack from Microsoft's website here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49978

You can find all kind of SDKs for both .Net Framework as well as .Net Core on the Microsoft site:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks